# yellow warning: 'AVCaptureVideoOrientation' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: Use AVCaptureDeviceRotationCoordinator instead

Tags: swift

Everyone,
I have a function for capturing photo. But after I upgrade it to iOS17, I got the above yellow warning in the line:

```
let videoPreviewLayerOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation = .portrait
```

How can I modify my code to eliminate the yellow warning?

```
/// - Tag: CapturePhoto
   

     public func capturePhoto() {
            
            if self.setupResult != .configurationFailed {
                let videoPreviewLayerOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation = .portrait
                self.isCameraButtonDisabled = true
                
                sessionQueue.async {
                    if let photoOutputConnection = self.photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
                        photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = videoPreviewLayerOrientation
                    }
                    var photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/4172595-videorotationangle

Comment: The warning, and the docs, tell you what to do

Answer (score 0):

I revised the codes as following, and then the yellow warning disappeared.Hope it's useful for others in future.

```
  /// - Tag: CapturePhoto
    public func capturePhoto() {
        if self.setupResult != .configurationFailed {
            self.isCameraButtonDisabled = true
            
            sessionQueue.async {
                if let photoOutputConnection = self.photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
                    photoOutputConnection.videoRotationAngle = 90
                }
                var photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
```